# What is a word for someone who pushes you down so they can benefit?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: they say bad things about you or make you mess up on a project so their's looks better. Almost like a bully, but not quite.

Comment: They're *sabotaging* you. They're a *sabotage*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone who says bad things about you could be a "backbiter" or a "backstabber"

Someone who makes you mess up could be a "saboteur".

Someone who does unethical things to promote their career could be a "neck-stepper".

Answer (score 2):

saboteur:

"a person who destroys or damages something deliberately : a person who performs sabotage"

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saboteur